# Laravel multi attach to relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have my user class, and a relationship in it:

```
App/User.php

public function benefits() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Advices', 'user_advices')
        ->withPivot('readed');
}
```

So I can attach Advices to my User doing this:

```
$user->benefits()->attach($advice);
```

How can attach one Advice to more than one User like this?:

```
//just a example
User::where(['id', '>', '5'])->benefits()->attach($benefit);
```

Is this even possible? maybe with a foreach?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have the `User` relationship set up in your `Benefit` model as well? Also, what version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent each()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each):

```
User::where(['id', '>', '5'])->each(function($user) use ($benefit){
    $user->benefits()->attach($benefit);
});
```